# NLog with LogEventInfo

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am using NLog 4.4.9 to log the info/error/exception. 
I am using following config settings and code to log exception. It logs other information but does not log exception. What am I doing anything wrong?

### Target setting for NLog

```xml
<target name="RollingFile" 
    layout="${log4jxmlevent:includeAllProperties=true}"
    type="File" 
    fileName="${LogDir}/webapi.log" 
    encoding="utf-8" 
    maxArchiveFiles="10" 
    archiveNumbering="Sequence" 
    archiveAboveSize="1048576" 
    archiveFileName="${LogDir}/{#######}.a">
```

### Code file

```
Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("ABC.Error");
LogEventInfo logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
logEventInfo.Level = LogLevel.Info;
logEventInfo.Message = "This is test message";
logEventInfo.Properties["UserId"] = "DAVESAURABH";
logEventInfo.Exception = e;
Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, logEventInfo);
```

Comment: It might help if you included more of the configuration file surrounding your target declaration. I am no NLog expert, but configuration errors could be a possible source of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the [default](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layouts) layout does NOT include the error e.g.

```
${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}
```

You'll have to add it manually e.g.

```
${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${error}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.